# Помогите разобраться с перезагрузкой оператора "+"

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

class Demo{
    int size = 0;
    int *p = nullptr;
public:
    Demo() = default;

    Demo(int i) :size(i){
        p = new int[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
            p[i] = rand() % 10;
    }
    //Конструктор корпирования
    Demo(const Demo &x){
        p = new int[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
            p[i] = x.p[i];
    }
    //Перезагрузка опиратора "+"
    Demo operator+(const Demo x){
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
            p[i] += x.p[i];
        return *this;
    }   
    //Перезагрузка опиратора присваивания
    Demo operator=(Demo x){
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
            p[i] = x.p[i];
        return *this;
    }

    ~Demo(){
        delete[] p;
    }
    void show(){
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
            cout << p[i] << ' ';
        cout << '\n';
    }   
};

int main(){
    srand(time(NULL));

    Demo a(5),b(5),c;
    a.show();
    b.show();

    c = a + b;
    c.show();

    return 0;
}
```

Когда я вывожу объект `c` то он выводит мусор, непонятные числа.

Comment: А в чем вопрос?

Comment: Опишите подробно вашу проблему. Иначе ваш вопрос может быть закрыт

Comment: Когда я вывожу объект "c" то он выводит мусор, непонятные числа

Comment: @IlyaTikhonov, пожалуйста, перенесите информацию из комментария в тело вопроса (кнопка "править" у поста).

Comment: @IlyaTikhonov, пожалуйста, перестаньте добавлять тег ООП к вопросам, Ваши вопросы никакого отношения к ООП не имеют.

Comment: @Ilya Tikhonov: А откуда взялся вот этот зоопарк способов передачи параметров? Конструктор копирования получает `const Demo &`. Оператор `+` получает `const Demo`. Оператор присваивания получает `Demo`. Какой логикой вы руководствовались, выбирая такие разные типы параметров (вместо того,чтобы везде сделать `const Demo &`)?

Comment: Я по книге делал, там похожий пример был, только без динамического выделения

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Явная ошибка в коде (даже если закрыть глаза на все допущения о необходимости совпадения размеров массивов и т.п.) - неправильно написанный конструктор копирования

```
Demo(const Demo &x){
    p = new int[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        p[i] = x.p[i];
}
```

Величина `size` в этом месте - неинициализированная переменная, содержащая бессмысленный мусор. А так как код постоянно (и в большинстве случаев - без нужды) вызывает конструктор копирования, то неудивительно, что получается ерунда.

Comment: я по книге делал, возможно я ошибся, а как должен быть в моём случае конструктор копирования ?

Comment: всё, нашёл ошибку

Answer (score 3):

То, как вы определяете оператор `operator +` большого смысла не имеет, так как два объекта класса `Demo` могут содержать массивы разных размеров и более того один из объектов может содержать нулевой указатель.

Оператор `operator +` имеет смысл определить как конкатенацию двух массивов.

Поэтому я определил бы его следующим образом

```
class Demo
{
//...
    friend Demo operator +( const Demo &lhs, const Demo &rhs );
//...
};

Demo operator +( const Demo &lhs, const Demo &rhs )
{
    Demo tmp;

    tmp.size = lhs.size + rhs.size;

    if ( tmp.size != 0 )
    {
        tmp.arr = new int[tmp.size];

        int *current = tmp.arr;

        if ( lhs.size != 0 )
        { 
            current = std::copy( lhs.arr, lhs.arr + lhs.size, current );
        }

        if ( rhs.size != 0 )
        { 
            std::copy( rhs.arr, rhs.arr + rhs.size, current );
        }
    }

    return tmp;
}
```

Вызов стандартного алгоритма `std::copy` вы можете заменить на обычные циклы. Например,

```
        if ( lhs.size != 0 )
        { 
            for ( int i = 0; i < lhs.size; i++ ) tmp.arr[i] = lhs.arr[i];
        }

        if ( rhs.size != 0 )
        { 
            for ( int i = 0; i < rhs.size; i++ ) tmp.arr[lhs.size + i] = rhs.arr[i];
        }
```

P.S.

> Помогите разобраться с перезагрузкой оператора “+”

**Перезагрузка** могла бы быть в отношениях с США, а в приложении к операторам языка C++ следует говорить о **перегрузке**. Вы сделали "ошибку наоборот" по отношению к ошибке, сделанной в свое время Хиллари Клинтон.:)

Answer (score 1):

Ну, проблема у вас не в перегруженном плюсе, проблема в общей семантике.

Когда вы присваиваете или складываете, вы не проверяете одинаковость размеров. Когда размеры разные, получается плохо, понятно.

Со сложением `a` и `b` вам повезло, поскольку у вас одинаковые размеры. А вот с присвоением `c` уже нет.

Следующая проблема — реализация сложения.

Ваш код вместо вычисления суммы модифицирует первое слагаемое. Это неправильно. Представьте себе, что код

```
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
int c = a + b;
```

приводит к тому, что `a` становится равным 3! Не очень хорошо, правда? Но именно это и делает ваш код: модифицирует первое слагаемое.

---

Ещё несколько не таких важных мелочей:

- конструктор по умолчанию, вероятно, лучше сделать приватным
- конструктор с `size` не проверяет, что `size > 0`
- оператор сложения должен бы получать операнд по ссылке, а не по значению
- да и оператор присваивания (если вы не применяете ухищрения наподобие move semantics)

Comment: если я даже пишу c(5), то всерав но мусор выводит

Comment: @IlyaTikhonov: почитайте обновление ответа.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: Тьфу, имел в виду оператор присваивания :)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: Да, а в нём-то всё плохо и без того.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Demo operator+(const Demo x){
> ```

Во-первых, лучше передавать константную ссылку, а не копию.
Во-вторых, ты на самом деле реализовал `+=` под видом `+`.
А мне вообще вариант со статической реализацией больше нравится.